# Why is my Risk Neutral Density recovery failing?

Tags: options, option-pricing, programming, risk-neutral-measure

I'm working on a project to recover a known Risk Neutral Density from option prices, using the Breeden-Litzenberger formula (assuming a continuum of option_price(strike_price), the second derivative of an option's price with respect to the strike price is equal to the risk-neutral probability density function of the underlying asset's price).

I'm testing my formula with a uniform RND, but **the recovered "density" ends up being 100 times larger than expected (100*densityR)**. The issue occurs no matter what density I use (uniform or an approximated-normal).

Here's what I'm doing:

1. I generate a linearly spaced returns vector and calculate StrikePrices.
2. I generate a uniform discrete density densityR.
3. I calculate option prices for puts (option price = discounted expected payoff under (strike prices, densityR) )
4. I calculate the second derivative of option prices with respect to strike prices to recover the density.

Both MATLAB and Python implementations yield similar discrepancies. Here are some screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/s66kOY8

**Why is the recovered "density" 100 times bigger than expected?** Where am I making a mistake? I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

MATLAB version:

```
r=0.02;
tau=0.25;
numElements = 10000;
currentPrice=49.75;

% Create returns as a linearly spaced vector from 0 to 2
returns = linspace(0, 2, numElements)';

StrikePrices = currentPrice * returns; 

% Create densityR as a uniform distribution
densityR = ones(numElements, 1) * (1 / numElements);

% Calculate the payoff for each option price
optionPrices = zeros(numElements, 1); % Initialize optionPrices array

% Adjusted loop to calculate option prices
for i = 1:numElements
    allPayoffsForCurrentStrike = max(0, StrikePrices(i) - StrikePrices);
    optionPrices(i) = sum(allPayoffsForCurrentStrike .* densityR) * exp(-r * tau);
end

optionPrices=optionPrices';

% Calculate the first derivative of optionPrices with respect to StrikePrices
dy_dx = gradient(optionPrices, StrikePrices);

% Calculate the second derivative of optionPrices with respect to StrikePrices
d2y_dx2 = gradient(dy_dx, StrikePrices);

first_derivative=dy_dx;
second_derivative=d2y_dx2;
sum_of_derivative=sum(second_derivative)

figure;
hold on; 
plot(dy_dx, 'o-', 'DisplayName', 'First Derivative'); 
plot(second_derivative, 'o-', 'DisplayName', 'Second Derivative'); 
plot(optionPrices, 'o-', 'DisplayName', 'Option Prices'); 
plot(StrikePrices, 'o-', 'DisplayName', 'Strike Prices'); 
plot(densityR, 'o-', 'DisplayName', 'Density R'); 
hold off; 
title('Second Derivative of Option Prices and Density R');
xlabel('Index');
ylabel('Value');
legend show; 
grid on; 

set(gca, 'YScale', 'log');
```

Python version:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Given parameters
r = 0.02
tau = 0.25
numElements = 10000
currentPrice = 49.75 

# Create returns as a linearly spaced vector from 0 to 2
returns = np.linspace(0, 2, numElements)

# Calculate StrikePrices
StrikePrices = currentPrice * returns

# Create densityR as a uniform distribution
densityR = np.ones(numElements) * (1 / numElements)

# Calculate the option prices
optionPrices = np.zeros(numElements)
for i in range(numElements):
    allPayoffsForCurrentStrike = np.maximum(0, StrikePrices[i] - StrikePrices)
    optionPrices[i] = np.sum(allPayoffsForCurrentStrike * densityR) * np.exp(-r * tau)

# Calculate the first derivative of optionPrices with respect to StrikePrices
dy_dx = np.gradient(optionPrices, StrikePrices)

# Calculate the second derivative of optionPrices with respect to StrikePrices
d2y_dx2 = np.gradient(dy_dx, StrikePrices);

# Sum of the second derivative
sum_of_derivative = np.sum(d2y_dx2)

# Plotting
plt.figure()
plt.plot(dy_dx, 'o-', label='First Derivative')
plt.plot(d2y_dx2, 'o-', label='Second Derivative')
plt.plot(optionPrices, 'o-', label='Option Prices')
plt.plot(StrikePrices, 'o-', label='Strike Prices')
plt.plot(densityR, 'o-', label='Density R')
plt.title('Second Derivative of Option Prices and Density R')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

print(f'Sum of the second derivative: {sum_of_derivative}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rescale the density of $S_T$, to recover the density of your return factor $R$. For example, if $R \sim U(0,2)$, then $S_T \sim U(0,2S_0)$.

As you have written it, the variable `densityR` does not denote the density of $R$ at each point, but rather the probability that $R$ lies in each partition interval. If you wish to compute the option-prices using Riemann sums, you could write

```
# Create densityR as a uniform distribution
densityR = np.ones(numElements) / 2
densityS = densityR / (currentPrice) # For the uniform distribution
# Compute asset density over StrikePrices

# Calculate the option prices
optionPrices = np.zeros(numElements)
for i in range(numElements):
    allPayoffsForCurrentStrike = np.maximum(0, StrikePrices[i] - StrikePrices)
    optionPrices[i] = np.sum(allPayoffsForCurrentStrike[:-1] * densityS[:-1] * np.diff(StrikePrices)) * np.exp(-r * tau)
```

If you compare `densityS` to the estimated density `d2ydx2`, you will find that they agree except at the very edges of their range (due to numerical errors).

Comment: Thank you, simply doing `densityS = densityR / (2*(currentPrice))`, and then using it instead of densityR in my original option price calculation ensures that (the second derivative of optionPrices with respect to StrikePrices) ≈ densityR. However, densityS sums to ~0.01, not 1. I've never done these sort of discretization problems before, so I might be missing something obvious. Can you tell me, and/or link me to further reading material, regarding why this rescaling is justified and necessary?

Comment: `densityS` represents the density of ST
 across the range defined in `StrikePrices`. We don't expect `densityS` to sum to 1, because the size/length of its domain ( `StrikePrices` ) is not 1.  Instead, we would expect `densityS` to integrate to 1, over all possible strike-prices.

 You can check that this is the case, by running `np.sum(densityS[:-1]*np.diff(StrikePrices)) `.

I think you are conflating "probabilities must sum to 1" with "the discrete sample of my density function must sum to 1" (which is incorrect).

Comment: I don't understand why `densityS = densityR / (2*(currentPrice))` gives us the density of ST across the StrikePrices range. How do you derive that from "the probability that R lies in each partition interval = densityR"?

Comment: This is because you have chosen the uniform distribution, and does not hold in general. IIUC, you define $R$ as being $\sim U(0,2)$, so its density $f_R(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ for $x \in [0,2]$. This means that $S_T = RS_0$ is $\sim U(0,2S_0)$, so its density $f_{S_T}(x) = \frac{1}{2S_0}$ for $x \in [0,2S_0]$.

Comment: In general, if $X$ has density $f_X$, then $Y = aX$ has density $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a}f_X(\frac{y}{a})$. However, in your case, may I ask why you don't just specify `\densityS` directly?

Comment: I understand that `densityS = densityR / (2*(currentPrice))` follows from the change of variables in probability. However, you said "densityR does not denote the density of R at each point, but rather the probability that R lies in each partition interval" - if that is so, how could we apply the change of variables rules, and produce a "discrete sample of the density function" - when densityR is apparently not a density?

Comment: Also, how would I specify densityS directly? Even if I do `StrikePrices = np.linspace(0, currentPrice*2, numElements)` and `densityS = np.ones(numElements) * (1 / numElements)`, I still get the same issue as before (https://imgur.com/a/jPpMvfA).

Comment: To specify `densityS` directly, you can write `densityS = np.ones(numElements)/(2*currentPrice)`, or `densityS = scipy.stats.uniform(StrikePrices, 0, 2*currentPrice)` .

Comment: I wrote `densityS = scipy.stats.uniform(loc=0, scale=2*currentPrice)`, and use it as `pdf_values=densityS.pdf(StrikePrices)` ... `probability_of_lying_in_each_interval=np.insert(pdf_values[1:]*np.diff(StrikePrices),0,0)` ... `optionPrices[i] = np.sum(allPayoffsForCurrentStrike * probability_of_lying_in_each_interval) * np.exp(-r * tau)`. When I do this, `np.sum(probability_of_lying_in_each_interval)=1`, and I do manage to recover the original PDF (https://imgur.com/a/1ty0MLm), and also the probability_of_lying_in_each_interval. Thanks.

Comment: I do think that the OLD calculation (`densityS = densityR / (2*(currentPrice))`) giving us the density of ST across the StrikePrices range wasn't correct. If I use it with `returns = np.linspace(0, 10, numElements)`...`densityS = densityR / (10*(currentPrice))` instead of `np.linspace(0, 2, numElements)` ... `densityS = densityR / (2*(currentPrice))`, the second derivative diverges from densityR: https://imgur.com/a/i565z1x. Actually, if we just increase numElements to 50000, there is a divergence too: https://imgur.com/a/Nn62kk6. Could ((OLD) densityS ≈ d2ydx2) have simply been a coincidence?

Comment: Great that you found a solution! The reason you get the *almost* correct (i.e. up to a scaling factor) for your old calculation is because of the scaling behavior of the uniform distribution. More precisely, the vector `np.ones(N)/N` is the pdf of a $U(0,N)$ variable, evaluated at $1,\ldots, N$, or *equivalently* the probability that a U(0,1) variable lies in the interval $(0,\frac{1}{N}),\ldots,(\frac{N-1}{N},1)$. So changing $N$ (or the upper bound in linspace) changes the scale factor you are off by. Hope this helps, else you can create a chatroom for continouing the conversation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the reputation to create a chatroom. What I meant by "coincidence" is that the 2nd derivative and densityR coincide ONLY when (`numElements = 10000` AND `returns = np.linspace(0, 2, numElements)` ... `densityS = densityR / (2*(currentPrice))` ) - increasing OR decreasing either `numElements` or the upper bound of `returns` causes the 2nd derivative and densityR to drift apart - I'm trying to understand this behavior.